# Powershell trouble getting value from key named count

Tags: json, powershell

I have a simple json that I am trying to get values from in Powershell

```ps
$webData = @'
{
            "results": [
               {
                  "facet": "266976",
                  "appid": "266976",
                  "count": 233206
               },
               {
                  "facet": "27096405",
                  "appid": "27096405",
                  "count": 85669
               }
            ]
}
'@

$data1 = $webData | ConvertFrom-Json 

Write-Output $data1.results.count
```

When I write output I get values count and not value itself like I do for appid and facet.
Desired result: 233206
Current result: 2

I cannot change json.
Is there a way for PS not to see it as a count operator?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) notes, in this case the array type's `ICollection.Count` property takes precedence over [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) of the array-element property named `Count`.

A simple workaround is to use the [intrinsic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#foreach) `.ForEach(string PropertyName)`:

```sh
$data1.results.ForEach('count')
```

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) notes, the type of `ForEach()` output is `` Collection`1 ``. If you actually need an array, use the array sub-expression operator `@()` or use the workaround suggested by Santiago, using `GetEnumerator()`.

```sh
$arrayOfCount = @($data1.results.ForEach('count'))
$arrayOfCount = $data1.results.GetEnumerator().Count
```

Output:

```text
233206
85669
```

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) noted, if you actually want to get the value of `count` for the **first** object only, you can write:

```sh
$data1.results[0].Count
```

Output:

```text
233206
```

Note that `Write-Output` is effectively redundant, because PowerShell *implicitly* outputs the "result" of any statement. So I've removed it in the samples above.